# A Gap in the Proof of the Duffin-Schaeffer's theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\varphi$ be the Euler totient function and $f$ be a nonnegative function such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)\varphi(n)}{n}=\infty,$$

and that

$$\limsup_{N\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N f(n) \varphi(n)/n}{\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)} >0.$$

Let $g(n)=\min(f(n),\frac{n}{6\varphi(n)})$ (the digit $6$ is not crucial for this question), then do we have

$$\limsup_{N\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N g(n) \varphi(n)/n}{\sum_{n=1}^N g(n)} >0?$$

I know an estimate $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n}{\varphi(n)} = \frac{315\zeta(3)}{2\pi^4} N + O(x^{\epsilon}), \forall \epsilon>0$, which might be helpful here (this estimate is not optimal, though).

---

For those who are curious about the source of this question. This is taken from Harman's Metric Number Theory, page 37. What I asked is a gap in Harman's proof of Duffin-Schaeffer's theorem in 1941.

Comment: You might be interested in the estimate that $\sum_{n\le N}{\varphi(n)\over n}={N\over\zeta(2)}+\mathcal O(\log N)$

Comment: @TravorLZH Yes, I know this estimate. But this probably doesn't help with this question...

Comment: It can be shown that if $g(n)$ is nondecreasing then there exists a definite constant $K>0$ such that $\sum_{n\le N}g(n)\varphi(n)/n\ge{1\over\zeta(2)}\sum_{n=1}^Ng(n)-Kg(N)\log N$

Comment: @TravorLZH Do you think you could write up a partial solution for this case when $g(n)$ is non-decreasing? I think it might be helpful for the general question. Thanks a lot!